# Converting []uint8/[]byte to hash table GoLang

Tags: json, go

My server sends a JSON response which looks like shown below

```
{"SortAs": "SGML","GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language","Acronym": "SGML","Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986"}
```

But My Go program receives it as type []uint8 .   Also the size JSON  sent from the server is not of definite size , it varies . How do i convert it  into a Hash table containing key/value pair again ?

Comment: So your json response is a key-value pair and you want to know how to turn this into a hashset/dictionary/map?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead :  yes , thats my objective !

Comment: Now that your duplicate question is gone... edit this one and include relevant information.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead , Edit done .

Comment: http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `byte` is an alias for `uint8`. Having said that what you want is a simple [json unmarshal](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal):

```
js := []byte(`{"SortAs": "SGML","GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language", "Acronym": "SGML","Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986"}`)

m := map[string]interface{}{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(js, &m); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Printf("%q",m)
```

Output (wrapped):

```
map["SortAs":"SGML" "GlossTerm":"Standard Generalized Markup Language"
    "Acronym":"SGML" "Abbrev":"ISO 8879:1986"]
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/2ZO2ixR48l).

Comment: getting this following error  " panic serving 127.0.0.1:33514: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type string
goroutine 6 [running]:"

Comment: @KarthicRao Your input json contains other types than just `string`s, e.g. lists or nested structs. Use `map[string]interface{}` map type then.